# Propel paginate() method doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, pagination, propel

I'm trying to do a pagination in the website I'm developing. I found that Propel has a paginate() method that is useful for doing this but I cannot make it work.

Here's some code:

```
$pager = ElementQuery::create()->paginate($page = 1, $maxPerPage = 10);
```

$pager should have the following methods, by Propel's official documentation:

```
$pager->getNbResults();   // total number of results if not paginated
$pager->haveToPaginate(); // return true if the total number of results exceeds the maximum per page
$pager->getFirstIndex();  // index of the first result in the page
$pager->getLastIndex();   // index of the last result in the page
```

And I should be able  to do something like this:

```
$links = $pager->getLinks(5);
```

But I'm just getting Element class methods.

Am I missing something?

[Here's where I got that information about pagination](http://propelorm.org/documentation/03-basic-crud.html) (to find it fast press `Ctrl + F` and type `paginate()`)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let me auto-answer my question... It seems those methods I mentioned are there, but for some reason they don't appear on my Netbeans editor when I write `$pager->`

I don't know if this counts as an answer but the "problem" is "solved"...